# how to fill only one row and one column in two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

What is a right way to fill the array - only first row and first column?
Filling the Edge array (which is one-dimensiona) works fine and I try do fill Matrix array the same way, but this doesn't work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Random rn = new Random();
          Graph gr = new Graph(rn.Next(1, 30), rn.Next(1, 30));
          Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public class Graph
        {
            private int[] Edge;

        private int n;
        private int m;

        private int x;

        private int[][] Matrix;

        public Graph(int _edge, int _matrix)
        {
            Random rn = new Random();
            x = rn.Next(0,30);

            Edge=new int[_edge];
            Matrix = new int[_matrix][];


            for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
            {
                Edge[i] = i;
                Console.WriteLine(Edge[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of nodes {0}", x);

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                {
                    Matrix[0][j] = j;
                    Matrix[i][0] = i;
                    Console.WriteLine(Matrix[i][j]);
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: you realize the last line is 

                    Console.WriteLine(Matrix[i][j]);

not                     Console.WriteLine(Matrix[j][i]);

Comment: @EricLizotte and? I have [i][j]

Comment: maybe my eyes bugged out reading it, I would swear the setter indexes were flipped the other way, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

"this doesn't work" probably means, you get a NullReferenceException.
After

```
Matrix = new int[_matrix][];
```

insert

```
for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.Length; ++i)
    Matrix[i] = new int[_matrix];
```

Comment: now the same exception but on this row: '  Matrix[i][0] = i;'

Comment: no, I still get an exception. But if it's in this order and with your code, i get exception on the second row:
Matrix[i][0] = i;
Matrix[0][j] = j;

Comment: @NickShepard what exception? What are the values of `x` and `_matrix`? You are creating arrays with random size and then access random elements inside. Obviously, this might access the array out of bounds.

Comment: But if I write not random it still doesn't work, Index out of range